# C# - Entity Framework inserting

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables Category and Product and I would like to insert products into categories. The table relation between these tables is one to zeor or one.

Category table:

```
CID : integer,
CategoryName : varchar,
```

Product table:

```
CID: integer, // foreign key to category table.
ProductName: varchar,
UnitsInstock: integer,
```

How can I write a simple query for inserting a product into the ProductTable? How do I handle the foriegn key situation? If the categoryid does not exists then the product should not be inserted.

I would realy appreciate any kinds of help.

Comment: What database software do you use? SQL Server already does that check for you, if you set it up correctly.

Comment: @LueTm - Iam using Sql Server. What I need to know is how to write the entity query for inserting a product into the product table, but only if the product id matches the the category id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be this one:

```
int categoryIdOfNewProduct = 123;
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    bool categoryExists = context.Categories
        .Any(c => c.Id == categoryIdOfNewProduct);

    if (categoryExists)
    {
        var newProduct = new Product
        {
            Name = "New Product",
            CategoryId = categoryIdOfNewProduct,
            // other properties
        };

        context.Products.Add(newProduct); // EF 4.1
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        //Perhaps some message to user that category doesn't exist? Or Log entry?
    }
}
```

It assumes that you have a foreign key property `CategoryId` on your `Product` entity. If you don't have one please specify more details.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a category to product would be many to one, but I would suggest studying the basics of Linq to Sql first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

[Linq to Sql 101](http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/series/linq_to_sql_101/)

[Learn the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723)